# How to write an abstract typescript generic type?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

given the following types

```ts
interface Base {
  id: string;
}

interface A extends Base {
  propA: string;
}

interface B extends Base {
 propB: string;
}
```

I would like to express a generic `MyGeneric<T>` with the following constraints:

1. `T` must be an object
2. `T` keys must be `string`
3. `T` values must be `instanceOf Base` (either of type `Base`, or of a type extending Base)

   (3. was *`T` values must be compatible with `Base` interface* but it has been reworded in order to avoid incomprehension)

I tried

```ts
interface MyConstraint {
  [key: string]: Base
}

interface MyGeneric<T extends MyConstraint> {
  data: T
}
```

But in this case, when the user wants to use it, it has 2 drawbacks:

```ts
interface userDefinedInterface1 {
  a: A;
  b: B;
}

function foo1(p: MyGeneric<userDefinedInterface1>):void {
  //drawback 1: this throws TS2344:
  //Type 'userDefinedInterface1' does not satisfy the constraint 'userDefinedInterface1'.   //Index signature is missing in type 'userDefinedInterface1'.
}

//to solve drawback 1, the user has to extend MyConstraint
interface userDefinedInterface2 extends MyConstraint {
  a: A;
  b: B;
}

function foo2(p: MyGeneric<userDefinedInterface2>):void {
  //drawback 2: here, ts considers every string property as valid because of [key: string] 
  console.log(p.data.arbitraryKey);//this is valid
}
```

Is there a way to define `interface MyGeneric<T>` to respect the 3 mentioned constraints without these 2 drawbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should solve both of your drawbacks:

```
type MyConstraint<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Base ? T[K] : never;
};

interface MyGeneric<T extends MyConstraint<T>> {
  data: T;
}
```

For the small price of making the `MyConstraint` generic. Both of your examples should now work plus of course if you did something like:

```
interface UserDefinedInterface3 {
  a: A;
  b: B;
  c: string;
}

type Wrong = MyGeneric<UserDefinedInterface3>;
```

You would get an error saying that types of property `c` are not compatible.

Comment: it says that `propB` should be never if  `MyGeneric<B>` is used: https://take.ms/BNOXJ

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question then - I thought your constraint should be an object with `Base` objects as values. `B` extends `Base` but it does not match the `T` type you described (point 3.). Can you clarify?

Comment: He asks: T must be an object, T keys must be string, T values must be compatible with Base interface. `B` is an object, `B` keys are string, `B` is compatible with `Base`, but `MyGeneric` doesn't allow it saying that `string` should be `never`, that breaks the 2nd requirement.

Comment: It seems I used a poor wording leading to incomprehension. I think @JánJakubNaništa got it right: I should have written for the 2nd requirement: _`T` values must be `instanceOf Base` (either of type Base, or of a type extending Base_.
I'll edit my post with this correction

Comment: In that case, if I understand correctly, `B` should not be a valid type argument for `MyGeneric` since its values are not extending `Base` correct? So `MyGeneric<B>` should indeed give you an error. However for example `MyGeneric<{ b: B }>` should be okay. Is my answer correct then?

Comment: @JánJakubNaništa you understand it correctly :-)
I have to leave for a bit, I'll test your answer in details in my full case once I'm back (my example was greatly simplified)

Answer (score 0):

There's only one limitation - if you want to add extra key you have to specify them.

```js
interface Base {
  id: string;
  num: number;
}

interface A extends Base {
  propA: string;
}

interface B extends Base {
 propB: string;
}

type MyGeneric<T extends Base, K extends keyof any = never> = {
  data: T & {
    [key in K | keyof T]: key extends keyof T ? T[key] : string;
  }
}


const test1: MyGeneric<B, 'test'> = {
  data: {
    id: '123',
    num: 123,
    propB: '123',
    test: '123',
  },
};
const test2: MyGeneric<B> = {
  data: {
    id: '123',
    num: 123,
    propB: '123',
    test: '123', // fails, it has to be provided in current TS.
  },
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChnLAAmAXMhmFKAOYDc+yIArgLZnMsBG09AvrrlCRYiFAEFkEAB6QQRDGkw4GABygB7FWLIUqIOrn6Dw0eEjSSZEOQvRZkeZGs2odlGnwFgAnipQBZbwBxa2hgBAAeABVLWXlFLAAaZABpWOt4gGsIb3UYZDgQb2QAXkYIADdoAD5ShwYiODA4MhiAMnqCAgBtbOLQVOQAH2Q+vOQogF0yPvSbUZzxmIB+Cd6cyeQ3PQMCfiNcBHUQCmRICgBGMkCQkDDI1GSAcnOwJ9qyx2RG5rIvgmIZCeFwATABmJ6JBgEDhkUFgqFdJwaFSuZDA8GQ6FnCAUIHwrF7KG8ehHE5gHEUEHXYKhKgPD6db5NFpMgGkdEExFdWHIeHcgjOVH4zECylgEUQ5IAemlyHgwAANhhksAKQALTBndTIbjI9QVYgQIiEEDIBBMKBQawUqIAZQAdAxeMTaEA)

If you want to rely only on keys of `T`.

then simply use this version:

```js
type MyGeneric<T extends Base> = {
  data: T & {
    [key in keyof T]: key extends keyof Base ? Base[key] : string;
  }
}
```